# Why is C4062 Visual C++ warning off by default?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, switch-statement, compiler-warnings

According to MSDN, Visual C++ can emit [C4062 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdt9w8tf.aspx) when

- and enumeration is used in `switch` and
- there's no label for at least one element of that enumeration and
- there's no `default:` label in the `switch`

Now to me such situation certainly deserves a warning - there's a good chance that the element in question is mishandled. If nothing has to be done for some elements - the developer can provide either an empty `case` or `default`.

What could be the reason why this warning is off by default?

Comment: A wild guess is that enabling it would break code from Microsoft headers. Enabling /Wall on one of my moderately sized C++ project yields 9812 warnings (!) from MS headers.

Comment: Are any warning defined in the standard or are they always implementation defined.

Comment: @rerun: good question (whose answer may be subtle). If you are interested in the answer, please ask it as a question on its own.

Comment: I completely agree with @AlexandreC.  Microsoft is obsessively concerned with backwards compatibility, and it can be a serious PITA sometimes.

Comment: You probably already realize this, but you can enable it with `/Wall`

Comment: Because people don't want to be saved from themselves. :)

Comment: @John Dibling: I tried `/Wall` - I didn't like it.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain folk (in which I include myself) who like to see '0 Warnings' whenever they build. Adding an empty case might be OK if you're only not handling a few cases, but if you're working say with an input library which gives you an enum showing which key is down, do you really want 200+ empty cases for the keys you don't process?

Of course, you might say just add an empty default case, but:

- It doesn't really make semantic sense in the above case
- Now you're just inviting [C4061](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96f5t7fy.aspx) (where does it all end?)

So it would really set my OCD on edge if I got these warnings by default

Comment: To be fair, I see no reason C4061 should exist.

Comment: Actually, I take that back; I could see a situation where you've extended an enumeration and want to make sure the new members aren't going to behave badly in a default block.  It would certainly be off by default, though.

Comment: Giving it some thought I would even say that 4061 is more useful by being more general, your code might be buggy do to not being handled _or_ being mishandled by `default`. Still think off-by-default is correct, it's a debug tool not everyone will need to use.

Answer (score 0):

If this warning is ON by default, then `enum`s may not remain extendable always, without editing the existing (already working) code. e.g.

```
// (c) 2009
// header.h
enum E { a, b, c };
...
// legacy.cpp
switch(e)
{
case a:  ...
case b:  ...
case c:  ...
}
```

Suppose, after 2 years developer edits just the `header.h`. The implementation file is well tested and not changed (`legacy.cpp`)

```
// (c) 2011
// header.h
enum E { a, b, c, d, e };  // added 'd','e'
```

Due to the mandatory warning, the `legacy.cpp` may get flooded with warnings at places where `d` and `e` not handled, which may not be desirable.

Comment: Often, especially when dealing with legacy code, this warning is of great help in catching potential bugs. So, I'd consider enabling it as a feature, not an issue.

Comment: See @Guy Cook's answer for the other side of that coin.

Comment: If you've changed E, you've potentially made a change in design intention.  I see this is as the reason to give the warning, not omit.

Comment: @Tom: Key word being "potentially."  Depending on how the enum is used, it might or might not be an issue.  If it would be an issue, turn it on and double check.  If it wouldn't, leave it off and move on with your day.

Comment: @Dennis Expecting every developer in an organization to turn on random warnings sporadically is so optimistic that its willful negligence.  Reviewing daily builds is probably more tenable.

Answer (score 0):

Those warnings are probably meant to be enabled on a case by case basis. Trying to compile a C++ project with `/Wall` yields thousands of warnings from Microsoft's own headers.

Now, you are trying to debug a large piece of code where you suspect that there is a `case` statement missing somewhere (or you want to rule out this hypothesis). You then enable C4062.

If you look well, all these disabled warnings are highly pedantic but have their use to track down obscure bugs. Do you really want to enable [C4264](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb55b5f4.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

People use enums for different reasons.

Lots of other people (Microsoft included, obviously) will use them with much less scrutinized intention.  They are just a named value, and their groupings aren't very interesting.  In their defense, they have a lot of ground to cover.

There are some edge cases like GuyCook's example that nobody will be happy with getting a warning about.  He's right that nobody wants to look at that crap.  In cases like that I've placed handling code in its own cpp file so it wasn't recompiled without a change to the header.  I wish there were a more convenient way to solve that problem, but I don't think there is.

I admire languages(C#/Java?) for their ability to ignore specific instances of a warning with annotations.

The fact that you are befuddled with its omission means you are probably using them in the way that they are the most meaningful in a design.  I personally think enums should be given the same scrutiny as classes in regards to coupling and cohesion.  If someone changes an enum, the code should be reviewed.  If someone changed an interface on a class you inherited from, you'd want to know about that, wouldn't you?

They don't *have* to use them in that way, though.  An enum is just a tool, some prefer to use it as a synonym for stuff. :)