# May I have a C# compile time error when a switch doesn't handle one or more enum values?

Tags: c#, .net, compile-time

Suppose I have a `switch` over some variable holding an enum:

```
SomeEnum variable;
switch( variable ) {
   case Option1:
      Magic1;
      break;
   case Option2:
      Magic2;
      break;
   default:
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

and I know that the `switch` must handle all possible enum values so that if a new value is added into the enum the `switch` must be altered and this is why I add `default` that throws an exception.

The problem is there's no error indication until the code is run and control passed through `default` and the exception is thrown (and btw the exception can well be silenced somewhere up the call stack).

I'd like to have a compile time error here. For example, Visual C++ can emit [C4062 warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7916923/57428) when there's no `default` and one or more value is unhandled and that warning can be promoted to an error. I could have just eliminated `default` in my code and make use of that warning.

Can I have something similar in C#?

Comment: That would certainly be a nice language feature.  F# gives you warnings in pattern matching if the test is not exhaustive, and it would be nice if C# did the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you will need to write a unit test. The compiler won't do that for you.

A unit test might look something like:

```
public void TestSwitch()
{
    foreach (var variable in (SomeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => YourMethod(variable), "Value {0} not supported", variable);
}
```

depending on your test framework.

Actually, any value of the underlying integral type (for example all 4,294,967,296 values if the underlying type is `int` which it almost always is) are possible, and you never write that many `case` labels, I presume. I know you want only the values with names, but as I said, the compiler will not check that for you. It only checks if two `case` refer to the same value.

I suggest you put:

```
if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SomeEnum), variable))
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

somewhere, if your enum does not have the `[Flags]` attribute, but it clearly only works at runtime.